# edit file in shell script

Tags: scripts

I'm new to Linux.
I'm running a simulation package on Linux. For each iteration, a file as below will be generated. I need to do some modification and then use the modified file as an input for the next iteration. I want to finish this modification by shell script then I don't need to do it manually after each iteration. The modification is as follows: 
there are x y z coordinates from the 9th line (below Direct). The third column of each line should be multiplied by a constant (say 1.03).

How should I do it in shell script? I can do that in MATLAB but I'm not familiar with the commands in linux.

Thank you!

####the generated file starts from next line

```
POSCAR for FCC Cu (created manually) 

   1.00000000000000

   7.6799999999999997    0.0000000000000000    0.0000000000000000

   3.8399999999999999    6.6509999999999998    0.0000000000000000

   0.0000000000000000    0.0000000000000000   41.0000000000000000
  72  40  40

Selective dynamics

Direct

  0.0000000000000000  0.0000000000000000  1.0000000000000000   F   F   F 

  0.9999979999999979  0.3328410000000019  1.0000000000000000   F   F   F

  0.9999960000000030  0.6656819999999968  0.0000000000000000   F   F   F

  0.3328369999999978  0.0000000000000000  0.0000000000000000   F   F   F

  0.3328360000000004  0.3328410000000019  2.0000000000000000   F   F   F

  0.3328339999999983  0.6656819999999968  3.0000000000000000   F   F   F

  0.6656750000000002  0.0000000000000000  5.0000000000000000   F   F   F

  0.6656729999999982  0.3328410000000019  2.0000000000000000   F   F   F

  0.6656710000000032  0.6656819999999968  1.0000000000000000   F   F   F
```

Comment: You might want to have a look at bc for the calculation part: http://www.basicallytech.com/blog/?/archives/23-command-line-calculations-using-bc.html As for accessing and editing a specific number, I think that sed or awk should be helpful (although the syntax is not that easy).

Comment: Is the file really double-spaced? I tried to fix your formatting, but that aspect was not clear.

Comment: No, it should be single spaced. The first time I submitted my question, I found the file content was all messed up. So i used double space to make it clear. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

To modify the 3rd space-separated field in all non-empty lines below the 9th, preserving the number formatting, you could do something like

```
awk 'NR>9 && NF {$3=sprintf("%.16f",$3*1.03);} 1' file
```

Note that it does not actually check that `$3` is a numeric field before attempting to multiply it.

Comment: Thank you very much. You are so nice. That's what I want. I will try to implement it into my shell file and run.